# jquery.ajax set with async=true to send data back to server not working if page redirects/reloads

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to save some content whenever a button/hyperlink is clicked using `jquery.ajax` (Using Asp.net 3.5). The logic is as follows:

- Through `.bind` in jquery I bind my own method(`MakeLog`) to a button click or hyperlink click. The click events of button/hyperlink contain nothing, I need to use `.bind` for selective controls.
- Now we have a button whose click event will fire a method, say `MakeLog`.
- Code snippet for `MakeLog` is as follows:

.

```
var xhr = jQuery.ajax({  
    url: "/Logger.aspx",  
    data: { content: logContent },  
    error: function(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert ("XmlHttpRequest: " +   XmlHttpRequest + 
               " textStatus: " + textStatus + "errorThrown: " + 
               errorThrown);
    },
    contentType: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",  
    success: function (xml, txtStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {  
       //alert("xml" + XmlHttpRequest);  
    },  
    async: true  
});
```

- This works fine in IE but in Firefox this is not sending the data back as expected.
- I tried to identify the issue and came across the following: [jQuery ajax calls async: false vs async: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522944/jquery-ajax-calls-async-false-vs-async-true)
- What I understand is that, whenver page is redirecting/reloading due to button click or   hyperlink click the async call is not working properly.

Comment: Do you want the button click to redirect/reload (as well as make the ajax call)?

Comment: Yes. The button click should work as normal. The MakeLog function that I bind usinig .bind should do some unobstrusive work asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a similar issue I encountered with AJAX event logging. This can be solved by loading pixel images via JavaScript. The reason is that page loads interrupt XmlHttp requests (your AJAX calls). Loading images, however, will not be interrupted by page loads.

See the following question I posted previously for reference:
[AJAX GET race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214023/ajax-get-race-condition)

Comment: Matt, Should I be putting that image request in my method before the ajax call? And wouldn't this be a synchronous call? Because I don't want synchronous communication in this method.

Comment: It should *replace* the AJAX call.  Take a look at the Image object in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#section_4

Comment: I tried the following, but to no avail:  
1. Added an empty image 2. Modified my function as follows: var image = new Image(1, 1); alert(image + "image"); image.onload = function () { <ajax call here> } img.src = "<empty image file src>"; Is this what you meant?

Comment: Also tried doing this: image.src = "/Logger.aspx?content=asdf"; (Setting image source to asp.net page and passing data through querystrings, again this works if there's an alert but not otherwise.)

Comment: No, you don't need an AJAX call.  The image you're loading replaces that.  Try something like this: `var img = new Image(1,1); img.src = '/Logger.aspx?any=data&that=you&need=sent&uniqueTimestampHere';` ... your Logger.aspx file should perform the tracking as it normally does based upon the parameters, but return a 1x1 pixel image or something. The uniqueTimestampHere value should just be the Javascript milliseconds since the Epoch or something to prevent the pixel image from being cached across requests.

Comment: Tried this but isn't working. I think the page reload/redirect might be cancelling the call, because the call is being made (I checked in firebug).